# How can I list the subcategories on woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is quite "simple" question, still, I havent found a good way to solve this.

What I'm trying to do is, before apply a filter, I want to get an list of the subcategories (I need their ID's) .

So, I tried with this

```
$args = array( 'hierarchical' => 1, 
    'show_option_none' => '', 
    'hide_empty' => 0, 
    'parent' => 12, 
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' ); 
$subcats = get_categories($args);
```

But seems like something is not good and I get this:

```
Array ( [WP_Errorerrors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid taxonomy ) ) [WP_Errorerror_data] => Array ( ) )
```

If I move the code where my filter is, I get an infinite loop error (which is worse), Still, I havent found why it is an invalid taxonomy... is there any easier way to get this?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is this code located? Remember that the taxonomies aren't initialized until the `init` hook so if you attempt to query them before that you'll probably get an invalid tax error.

Comment: I have it at my functions inside of a if (is_admin()) , before call an "add_filter" method, where should it be?

Comment: I would wrap it in its own function and add it to a hook.

Comment: Never mind, while that is still true, the main problem is that you are using `get_categories()` when you aren't querying categories. You need 'get_terms()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) automatically assumes the taxonomy is `category`. Product Category is a custom taxonomy (`product_cat`), so you need to use [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

```
function sub_cats(){
    $args = array( 'hierarchical' => 1, 
        'hide_empty' => 0, 
        'parent' => 12 ); 
    $subcats = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args);

var_dump($subcats); 
}
add_action('init', 'sub_cats', 20 );
```